# Como permitir upload de imagens com no maximo 5mb com esse script?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Não entendo quase nada e quero ajudar um amigo. Ele tem um *script* que redimensiona a imagem antes de fazer o *upload* e salva a imagem redimensionada com `PHP`. Acontece que ele gostaria de colocar um limite máximo de *MBs* para a imagem impedindo que o usuário envie imagens gigantescas, sobrecarregando o servidor.

Segue abaixo o *script*:

```
// Iniciando biblioteca
var resize = new window.resize();
resize.init();

// Declarando variáveis
var imagens;
var imagem_atual;

// Quando carregado a página
$(function ($) {
    // Quando selecionado as imagens
    $('#imagem').on('change', function () {
        enviar();
    });
});

/*
 Envia os arquivos selecionados
 */
function enviar(){

    // Verificando se o navegador tem suporte aos recursos para redimensionamento
    if (!window.File || !window.FileReader || !window.FileList || !window.Blob) {
        alert('O navegador não suporta os recursos utilizados pelo aplicativo');
        return;
    }

    // Alocando imagens selecionadas
    imagens = $('#imagem')[0].files;

    // Se selecionado pelo menos uma imagem
    if (imagens.length > 0){

        // Definindo progresso de carregamento
        $('#progresso').attr('aria-valuenow', 0).css('width', '35%').html('Carregando..');
            // Escondendo campo de imagem
        $('#imagem').hide();
        // Iniciando redimensionamento
        imagem_atual = 0;
        redimensionar();
    }
}

    /*
     Redimensiona uma imagem e passa para a próxima recursivamente
     */
    function redimensionar(){

        // Se redimensionado todas as imagens
        if (imagem_atual > imagens.length){

            // Definindo progresso de finalizado
            $('#progresso').html('Imagem enviada com sucesso');

            // Limpando imagens
            limpar();

            // Exibindo campo de imagem
            $('#imagem').show();

            // Finalizando
            return;
        }

        // Se não for um arquivo válido
        if ((typeof imagens[imagem_atual] !== 'object') || (imagens[imagem_atual] == null)){
            // Passa para a próxima imagem
            imagem_atual++;
            redimensionar();
            return;
        }

        // Redimensionando
        resize.photo(imagens[imagem_atual], 800, 'dataURL', function (imagem) {

            // Salvando imagem no servidor
            $.post('ajax/salvar.php', {imagem: imagem}, function() {

                // Definindo porcentagem
                var porcentagem = (imagem_atual + 1) / imagens.length * 100;

                // Atualizando barra de progresso
                $('#progresso').text(Math.round(porcentagem) + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', porcentagem).css('width', porcentagem + '%');

                // Aplica delay de 1 segundo
                // Apenas para evitar sobrecarga de requisições
                // e ficar visualmente melhor o progresso
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // Passa para a próxima imagem
                    imagem_atual++;
                    redimensionar();
                }, 100);

            });

        });
    }
```

Como faço para limitar em, no máximo, 5MB o tamanho da imagem que será carregada? É possível criar algo que verificasse o tamanho da imagem antes de fazer o *upload* e antes de começar a fazer o redimensionamento dela e salvar via php?

Comment: É melhor fazer essa validação com php, do lado do servidor

Comment: Todo seu código é javascript, esquece isso, não tem como confiar em nenhum javascript. O usuário inclusive pode estar com isso desligar ou pode fazer o envio do arquivo fora de um navegador, ignorando qualquer validação do javascript. Quer limitar? Use `upload_max_filesize`, não é suficiente? Use `client_max_body_size` no NGINX (ou equivalente em outros webservers), para não depender somente do PHP. Se já fez isso e deseja quer apenas mostrar um aviso (dizendo que excede o limite, por ex.) no javascript a questão é outra, então você não quer impedir que sobrecarreguem, os objetivos são outros.

Comment: Sim, meu objetivo é apenas fazer uma verificacao e mostrar um aviso . Quanto a impedir do lado do servidor.. é uma otima ideia tbm. mas gostaria de fazer essa pequena funcao de verificar o tamanho do arquivo e fazer um alerta